# WebApp needs to do something first time only, where to put that logic? Flask or django

Tags: python, flask

The web app I am working on needs to perform a first-time setup or initialization,

where is a good place to put that logic? I dont want to perform the check if a configuration/setup exists on each request to / or before any request as thats kind of not performant.

I was thinking of performing a check if there is a sane configuration when the app starts up, then change the default route of / to a settings/setup page, and change it back. But thats like self-changing code a bit.

This is required since the web app needs settings and then to index stuff based on those settings which take a bit of time. So after the settings have been made, I still need to wait a while until the indexing is done. So even after the settings/setup has been made, any requests following, will need to see a "wait indexing" message.

Im using flask, but this is relevant for django as well I think.

EDIT: Im thinking like this now;

When starting up, check the appconfig.py for MY_SETTINGS, if it is not there
add a default from config.py and put a status=firstrun object on the app.config, also
change the / route to setup view function.
The setup view function will then check for the app.config.status object and perform
The setup of settings as necessary after user input, when the settings are okay,
remove app.config.status or change it to "indexing", then I can have a before_request function to check for the app.config.status just to flash a message of it.
Or I could use the flask.g instead of app.config to store the status?

Comment: Sounds like you're optimizing code very early. If you really think this check is going to kill performance,you might want to use a try/except statement as its more efficient when you're expecting mostly successes.

Comment: It feels wrong to perform a check on each request when I know its going to hit only in possibly less than 1% of the requests.

Comment: Well then you can raise an exception in your views when you happen to notice you're not configured, and catch it with middleware (at least on Django).

Comment: Flask doesnt support middleware I think... how would this be done in django without try except ?

Comment: Of course it does. `app.wsgi_app = SomeMiddleware(app.wsgi_app)`

Comment: I can't speak for Flask, but on Django you'll just need to use the process_exception function on your middleware and raise an exception anywhere in your code. Alternatively and still on Django, you can have a middleware that will check whether you're configured in its __init__ method and redirect all requests towards the configuration page if you're not, and deactivate itself otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is creating a CLI script, preferably via [`Flask-Script`](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Script/) if you use Flask (in Django it would be the default `manage.py` where you can easily add custom commands, too) and defining a function such as `init` or `install`:

```
from flaskext.script import Manager
from ... import app
manager = Manager(app)
@manager.command
def init():
    """Initialize the application"""
    # your code here
```

Then you mention it in your documentation and can easily assume that it has been run when the web application itself is accessed.

Comment: But I want the user to have a web interface to the settings/configuration of the application, not cli. Then I could have just told them change config.py as well

Comment: The point of the web application is to be that a web application, not a software as a service thing. Download package, clicketyclick it, and in the browser you have the application ready to go.

Comment: Well you didn't mention the kind of config data. If it would be stuff such as paths and database connectivity data (i.e. things you usually do not want to change later) my answer would have been more appropriate. Besides that, python web applications usually involve editing a config file or .htaccess anyway since you don't just "upload and use" a WSGI app (like you do with PHP (cr)apps)

Comment: Im not making a webapp to upload somewhere and serve many users, Im making a webapp which anyone downloads and runs as any other program, which then connects to a p2p net, where the discovery phase is over http.